# Connect from Sourcetree to Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I have a repo in Azure DevOps Server 2020 (on-premise), which contains a lot of files. I'm trying to use Sourcetree to maintain changes in repo.

Sourcetree has an option to setup remote account to connect to ADS. But I cannot connect to ADS, I get strange errors.

I tried using Host URL with only domain, with collection name and even with project name, but no success :(

Settings before clicking "Refresh Personal Access Token".

[image]

Then I add my PAT via "Refresh Personal Access Token", I use my ADS username (integrated with Active Directory) and PAT as password:

[image]

I get the error after enterring username and PAT:

[image]

So my questions:

1. Is my authenication flow correct?
2. Should I use only hostname as "Host URL" in Sourcetree or I should add also Organisation (Collection) and Project name?
3. What should I use in PAT request:

- Active Directory username (with domain or not?) and PAT as password?
- PAT as username and as password?
- PAT as password and no username?
- something else?

Comment: May I know if the answer below helps?

Answer (score 0):

> Sourcetree has an option to setup remote account to connect to ADS.
> But I cannot connect to ADS, I get strange errors.

The `Remote` option is only for `Azure DevOps Services`, the on-premise `Azure DevOps Server` is not supported with this option. Something like `Bitbucket` and `Bitbucket Server`, they have different authentication methods

[image]

E.G The Azure DevOps Services `https://dev.azure.com/{org}` works as expected:

[image]

For on-premise Azure DevOps Server, we can use the `Clone` option, just copy the specific repo URL from your project, then set the local path to clone. After that you can change your source files on your local repo and push them to remote repo.

[image]
[image]